# Why do spammers not spoof the sender address as an email likely to be already whitelisted or trusted?

Tags: spam-prevention

I realize that if they spoofed from @google.com and it's sent to a gmail address, it will show as spoofed. Wouldn't showing images aid them in proving that someone read the email? Or do spammers not use web 1x1 transparent tracking pixels, as websites do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would imagine that trusted/whitelisted addresses are pretty dependent on the sender and recipient, ie not global, and it is unlikely the spammer would be able to discern these.

A lot of spam is sent from compromised accounts, and is actually very primitive in nature, and I expect that is part of the reason that 1x1 transparent pixel tracking is not practical.  Another reason is that having tracking pixels can help track down the spammer, and requires more sophisticated spammers.

Another thing to bear in mind is that a lot of the bigger / more trusted providers use things like DKIM and SPF which make it very hard for the spammer to spoof a particular address if the source of the spam is wrong - and a lot of spam is distributed or coming from hacked servers.

Comment: Right, but outlook with an imap/pop account does not do these checks, afaik. I'm sure there are plugins for it an Thunderbird as well as other apps. Also with all the tor to web gateways we could see this change.

Answer (score 0):

It comes down to simplicity. Most of the time it is a bot sending out mass emails. Think of it as a brute force attack combined with phishing. The bot sends out a frak ton of emails in the simplest way, eventually they will make there way into the inbox where someone will open the email+attachment, or follow a link to a phishing site.

I had to set up a phishing site back while I was in uni, Our assignment was to compromise another team in the class's Lab PCs, My partner and I decided on a simple spamish/phish attack since we knew the member of another team(Who happened to be our assigned target, everyone was randomly given a target, and no one knew who was targeting whom.) checked his email at the beginning of class. I talked to one of the network admin at my school and got permission to set up a bogus email account. The email address I chose was the same as our instructor's email, except I swapped two letters in the middle of her name, and emailed him pretending to be our instructor with an attachment that had embedded code which allowed my partner and me remote access. While what I a specific target, and Spambots use a "spray and pray" or something akin to a brute force approach, the goal is ultimately the same.

I am sure there are more complex ways being used. The vast majority I have to clean up after(I am a network admin.) are simple phishing attempts. I hope I answered your question.

Source: What I remember from Ethical Hacking, and personal experience.

Answer (score 0):

If these checks were built in to outlook, we would probably see fewer cryptowall infections (they are usually from a fedex or usps address), but as always user training is better, because ultimately they can choose to open an attachment if it gets past the scanners. Sorry to go off in a different, offtopic tangent!